# I can't install Netbeans in lion

Tags: macos, java

Netbeans is my usual IDE for developing.Today I formatted my mac and install a new lion.When I wan't to install netbeans,It I stuck at disk selecting step.I cannot choose my hard drive,the information below is like(sorry,I am using Chinese system and I don't know exactly what is said in English)'NetBeans 7.0.1 can't install on this drive,It can be installed but only use for Java 6'

I have no idea about issue,Is there anybody meet and solved this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple stopped bundling Java with the OS with Lion - you need to [install it](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1421).